# Choose Select box option by class name with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a select box as follows:

```
<select id="test">
    <option class="yyy">Val 1</option>
    <option class="zzz">Val 2</option>
    <option class="xxx">Val 3</option>
</select>
```

I want to make the second option with class `zzz` as selected, this should be by class name of the option and not by it's value.

Here is my code(not working):

```
var should_be_selected = 'zzz';
$(#test).children().hasClass(should_be_selected).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you know what hasClass returns?

Comment: there is no value for the options? why is it?

Comment: @ArunPJohny actually there is in my real scenario, but I needed to select them by class for some reasons, so I didn't write them here...

Comment: @Zenith `The .hasClass() method will return true if the class is assigned to an element`

Comment: Exactly, so why are you trying to make the value 'true' selected? :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
    var should_be_selected = 'zzz';
    $('#test').find('.' + should_be_selected).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: I tried this code. It worked for me BUT the "selected" attribute does not get removed when selecting another item. It means you can select "val 1", then select "val 2" it works. But if you try to select "val 1" again, it does not work anymore.

I fixed that using the code of @IvanChernykh below replacing `.attr` with `.prop` and now it's perfect.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
var should_be_selected = '.xxx';
$('#test').find(should_be_selected).prop('selected', true)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KrPDs/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
var should_be_selected = '.zzz';
$(should_be_selected , $("#test")).prop('selected', 'selected');
```

Literally , it means "Find elements with class name `zzz` inside of (in context of) element with `test` id and set their `selected` property to `selected`."

Comment: I tried your code but it did not work for me. However, it helped me fix the above code from @sangramparmar based on your code: `.prop` solved it. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Option having specified class

```
  $('option.zzz').prop('selected', true);
```

Note can start with dropdown having specific id with option having specific class, in case of multiple ones